# Are the $p$-adic digits of roots of unity equidistributed?

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-numbers, equidistribution

I was looking at the $p$-adic expansions of roots of unity in $\mathbf{Z}_p$, and I noticed that the digits tended to be equidistributed among the numbers $\{0, 1, \dots, p-1 \}$. I wanted to ask if anyone knew whether or not the following statement was correct:

> Suppose that $\alpha \in \mathbf{Z}_p$ is a root of unity, and that $\alpha$ is not equal to $1$ or $-1$. Then the digits of the $p$-adic expansion of $\alpha$ are equidistributed among the numbers $\{0, 1, \dots, p-1 \}$.
>
> That is, let's write $\alpha = \sum a_n  p^n$, where the digits $a_n$ all belong to the set $\{0,1,\dots, p-1\}$. Then for all $b \in \{0,1,\dots, p-1\}$, we have
> $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N} \, \#\{n \leq N : a_n = b \} = \dfrac{1}{p}.$$

This statement is false if $\alpha$ is equal to $1$ or $-1$ because if $\alpha=1$, then $p$-adic expansion of $\alpha$ is just $1$, and if $\alpha=-1$, the coefficients of the $p$-adic expansion are always $p-1$. But for remaining values of $\alpha$, my numerical experiments in Sage suggest that the coefficients are indeed equidistributed. Does anyone know whether or not this statement is true, and if so, if there is a reference with a proof?

Comment: Given the state of analogous conjectures for expansions of real algebraic numbers, my guess would be that the answer is yes but we don't have the tools to prove it

Comment: @Wojowu Interesting - any references to these analogous conjectures for real algebraic numbers? I'd be curious to read about them.

Comment: I don't have any references, those are pretty folklore conjectures. But our state of knowledge on them is very poor, e.g. we don't even know whether the decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$ contains each digit infinitely many times, which is a far cry from equidistribution.

Comment: You could make the same conjecture about nearly any other "naturally occuring" irrational number in $\mathbf Z_p$, such as $\sqrt{1+p}$ for $p > 2$ and $\sqrt{5}$ in $\mathbf Z_2$.  After all, by the ergodic theorem almost every number in $[0,1]$ has equidistibuted digits in every base and the same holds for almost every $p$-adic integer in the usual base $p$ expansion (again by the ergodic theorem). Look up "normal number".